# Wifi connection not durable with ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available

Tags: networking, drivers, internet, ethernet, realtek

Yesterday I have formated my computer and set Windows and Ubuntu 19.04.
Previously I had Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows and everything worked fine.

But now, when I visit big webside or download something, the internet stops and the only way to get it back is turn wifi off and on. But it is quite annoying as you may suspect.

When I ping google.com and during running it I start to download anything the "No buffer space available" message appear.

```bsh
$ ping google.com
64 bytes from waw02s17-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:401b:807::200e): icmp_seq=562 ttl=55 time=14.2 ms
64 bytes from waw02s17-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:401b:807::200e): icmp_seq=563 ttl=55 time=9.76 ms
64 bytes from waw02s17-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:401b:807::200e): icmp_seq=564 ttl=55 time=10.8 ms
ping: sendmsg: No buffer space available
```

I've tried to google it and I found a lot of potential solutions but none of it worked.

1. I tried increase buffer by chaning the value of `proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max`
2. I've change the configuration in this file `/etc/sysctl.conf` and added this:

```
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912
net.core.wmem_default = 524288
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 10240 87380 12582912
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 524288 524288 524288
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 5000
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1
net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 0
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_fack = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_ecn = 0
net.ipv4.route.flush = 1
```

Ofc after applying it I ran `sudo sysctl -p` and rebooted computer.

3. At last I tried to reinstall Ethernet driver

DEBUG INFO:
My NIC is Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411. I've found that many people also had a problem with it; but as I said on my previos Ubuntu on the same laptop I did not had such a problem.

```
$ lspci | grep -i ethernet
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

```
$ ifconfig
enp4s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 54:ab:3a:9b:f0:57  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 128  base 0x5000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5936  bytes 557194 (557.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5936  bytes 557194 (557.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.129  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 2a02:a310:462:b200:ac14:df84:b0f4:c30e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::4124:86b0:667a:ce5e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2a02:a310:462:b200:cdec:11a8:1953:57c7  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 40:49:0f:6f:93:21  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 319194  bytes 420767039 (420.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59135  bytes 11130642 (11.1 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And that's driver I have reinstalled

```
$ ethtool -i enp4s0f1
driver: r8168
version: 8.047.04-NAPI
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 0000:04:00.1
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
```

I know that this question was asked several times, but to be honest I have no idea if I did something wrong (like reinstalling driver) or I did not find some obvious solution. 
So every help will be great!

**EDIT1**

```
$free -h
              total       used       free    shared   buf/cache    available
Mem:       7,7Gi       1,5Gi       4,2Gi       436Mi       2,0Gi       5,4Gi
Swap:       1,9Gi          0B       1,9Gi
```

```
$sudo lshw -C network
*-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: 40:49:0f:6f:93:21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.0.0-31-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.0.129 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:132 memory:94200000-943fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.1
       logical name: enp4s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 54:ab:3a:9b:f0:57
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8168 driverversion=8.047.04-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:127 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:94404000-94404fff memory:94400000-94403fff
```

**EDIT 2**

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=6f325414-8363-4321-accd-293a9df2c941 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=80E4-D98C  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda10 during installation
UUID=1a73b541-6f90-495e-8e9a-62d5ee51348d /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=a759fb41-aee4-44ff-8122-99c8fa2f2ce9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

```
$ free -h
              total       used       free    shared   buf/cache    available
Mem:       7,7Gi       1,4Gi       4,3Gi       378Mi       2,0Gi       5,6Gi
Swap:       1,9Gi          0B       1,9Gi
```

[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGmb1.png)

Comment: Is your problem when connected via ethernet, or wifi. You indicate wifi, but are manipulating the ethernet driver. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Also, I'd recommend removing the changes you made to /etc/sysctl.conf and rebooting. Do you have DSL or cable modem?

Comment: @heynnema Wifi, I didn't know it was ethernet driver. I updated my question with more data, and I will remove changes made to `/etc/sysctl.config`. I have cable modem.

Comment: Try two SEPARATE tests... 1) boot to a kernel older than -31 from the GRUB menu and retest for wifi/ping problem, 2) when booted to -31 kernel, in `terminal` type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80` and retest for wifi/ping problem. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Sorry, can you be more specific about version I should use? -31 doesn't tell me a lot. Did you mean older than 3.1? https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: If you look at the GRUB menu, the second line should be `Advanced Options`. Select that, and you'll be given a list of installed/bootable kernels. First on the list should be the -31 kernel. I want you to try an older kernel, like -30 or -29, and retest for your wifi/ping problem.

Comment: @heynnema Okay, so I ran both test. I've used -13 version (the only one which wasn't -31 on grub menu). 1) Didn't work. 2) It's better. I could have download Anaconda (0.5GB) in less than 1 minute, which was almost impossible before change of swappiness. But when I wanted to download it second time there was "sendmsg: No buffer space available"

Comment: ok, good. Now lets repeat test #2, and after getting the no buffer error, show me `free -h` again. Also show me `cat /etc/fstab` and a screenshot of `gparted`.

Comment: @heynnema Done. I got buffer error, and after that get free -h.

Comment: Please see my answer, below. Not a 100% guarantee of a fix, but it's easy to try, and it's reversible. Report back.

Answer (score 1):

**Switch from a 2G swap partition, to a 4G /swapfile, and change vm.swappiness.**

Note: all of these changes can be easily reversed.

---

In `terminal`... create a new 4G /swapfile...

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo rm /swapfile
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

Use the `free -h` or `swapon` command to confirm 4G swap.

Edit `/etc/fstab` (`sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab`), and change this...

```
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=a759fb41-aee4-44ff-8122-99c8fa2f2ce9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

To this...

```
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
# UUID=a759fb41-aee4-44ff-8122-99c8fa2f2ce9 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

And add this...

```
# swap was moved to /swapfile
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

Save the file and quit gedit.

For vm.swappiness temporary change...

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80
```

For vm.swappiness permanent change...

- edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` (`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`)
- add `vm.swappiness=80`
- save the file and quit gedit
- reboot

Comment: I've applied all your changes and it didn't work on -31 and on -13. During 'stress test' I've been checking swap using `free -h` and it was all the time equal to 0.

Comment: @AlbertRoethel and `free -h` or `swapon` shows 4G swap? And the ping/buffer problem still occurs? Try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the problem still occurs. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

In my situation it was the fault of the wifi changing channels. I enforced the stable channel and channel width of 20MHz (instead of 80/40/20) in the router settings and wifi works without crashes.